# Mysql return results based on SUM of a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query where I need to get all customers where they have spent less that a certain amount in a given month and return only those that have not met the quota.

The query as it is now is as follows.

```
SELECT cus.id, cus.email_address, COALESCE(SUM(credit_total),0) AS totalSpend
FROM customers AS cus
LEFT JOIN tasks_custs AS tsk ON tsk.user_id = cus.id
WHERE (
YEAR(date_ordered) = '2013'
AND MONTH(date_ordered) = '09'
AND paid = '1'
AND totalSpend < '300'
)
```

The error that is being returned is Unknown column 'totalSpend' in 'where clause'.

What I am wondering is can I accomplish what I am trying to do with a single sql query or am I going to have to select all customers and check the spend using php.

I was hoping to just have mysql return only the results that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with aggregate functions you need to use the `HAVING` keyword instead of `WHERE`.

```
SELECT cus.id, cus.email_address, COALESCE(SUM(credit_total),0) AS totalSpend
FROM customers AS cus
LEFT JOIN tasks_custs AS tsk ON tsk.user_id = cus.id
WHERE (
YEAR(date_ordered) = '2013'
AND MONTH(date_ordered) = '09'
AND paid = '1')
GROUP BY cus.id
HAVING SUM(credit_total) < 30
```

If you are interested here is a [good explanation](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/) in the difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` look here. But if you want a quick summary,in my words, I would say it is this:

- `WHERE` conditions are applied **before any grouping** on the specified criteria, and cannot be applied to aggregate functions
- whereas `HAVING` is applied **after grouping** and can use aggregate functions to filter the result set.

Comment: This killed the error now I just need to figure out why it is returning 0 results. When I know there are customers in the database that would be returned

Comment: NM I was missing the GROUP BY cus.id now it works perfect. Thanks GordyD for the quick solution. I will update your answer as correct when timer runs out.

Comment: I think it is probably because you are missing a GROUP BY!

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you? I have group'ed customer information and summed the total, just like you have - except that I have added a HAVING CLAUSE after grouping the data.

```
SELECT 
    cus.id, 
    cus.email_address, 
    COALESCE(SUM(credit_total),0) AS totalSpend
FROM customers AS cus
LEFT JOIN tasks_custs AS tsk 
    ON tsk.user_id = cus.id
WHERE
    YEAR(date_ordered) = '2013'
    AND MONTH(date_ordered) = '09'
    AND paid = '1'
GROUP BY 
    cus.id, 
    cus.email_address
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(credit_total),0) < '300'
```